# Проблема с запуском скрипта через cron

Tags: cron

debian, apache2

Через **crontab -e** добавил в конец:

```
*/1 * * * * php /var/www/http://site.ru/main/cron/index?token=TOKEN > /tmp/lcron.log 2>&1
```

Но в **lcron.log** пишет:

> Could not open input file: /var/www/http://site.ru/main/cron

Права на файл **cron** поставил 777, всё равно не работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разобраться в сложившийся ситуации.

Comment: А вы расширение `php` у index не забыли указать?

Comment: @rjhdby, пробовал так, всё равно такая же ошибка.

Comment: У Вас действительно есть каталог `/var/www/http://site.ru/main/cron/index?token=TOKEN` ? O.O В противном случае зачем Вы пытаетесь передать это интерпретатору?

Comment: @nobody, конечно, такого каталога нет, полный путь я писал ниже. Но, пока перед http я не добавил /var/www/ - была ошибка not found.

Comment: @Максим ещё раз покажите что Вы пишите в крон, какую ошибку получаете и какого результата пытаетесь достичь?

Comment: @nobody, если в браузере выполнить: http://site.ru/main/cron/index?token=TOKEN, то скрипт отрабатывает на ура, как и положено. Теперь мне нужно сделать выполнение этого скрипта через крон. Собственно, что я пишу в крон и какая выходит ошибка я написал в 1-ом посту.

Comment: @nobody, проще говоря, через крон нужно не только вызвать скрипт, но и передать ему аргумент (токен).

Comment: @Максим э-э-э, я не уверен, что у Вас получится выполнить это из командной строки... тем не менее попробуйте для начала вызвать этот скрипт из командной строки написав `php /тут/точный/путь/к/скрипту` . Если не сможет найти php - выполнить `which php` , чтоб узнать где он находится на Вашем сервере. Скорее всего для debian это `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: @nobody, ну, вот выполнил я: php /var/www/application/controllers/main/cron.php и получил ошибку: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Controller' not found in /var/www/application/controllers/main/cron.php on line 2

Почему через крон не получится передать параметр?

Comment: @Максим очевидно, Вы не правильно пишите имя скрипта, либо не правильно передаёте туда аргументы. Вот пример, как это можно делать из командной строки либо через крон (Что, по-сути, та же командная строка): http://web-polyglot.ru/2009/12/19/peredacha-parametrov-v-php-skript-zapuskaemyj-cherez-cron/

Answer (score 2):

**UPD** Из комментария.

> полный путь к фалу: /var/www/application/controllers/main/cron.php
>   Пробовал как вы писали выше, всё равно такая же ошибка. В файл
>   cron.php должен передавать токен.

1. Необходимо поменять вызов скрипта таким образом

`*/1 * * * * php /var/www/application/controllers/main/cron.php?token=TOKEN > /tmp/lcron.log 2>&1`

Убедитесь, что пользователю, от чьего имени будет работать задание cron, доступен этот файл

2. В cron'е лучше использовать полные пути. Плохо `php`, хорошо(например) `/usr/local/php`.

Comment: полный путь к фалу: /var/www/application/controllers/main/cron.php

Пробовал как вы писали выше, всё равно такая же ошибка. В файл cron.php должен передавать токен.

Comment: @Максим обновил ответ

Comment: такая же ошибка..

У меня по такому пути: /usr/local нет php

Answer (score 2):

wget хороший и универсальный вариант, но, справедливости ради, зачастую не единственный.

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /var/www/application/controllers/main/cron.php on line 2

Такие ошибки, как правило, возникают из-за того, что в скрипте, вызываемом через cron, подключаются другие файлы по относительному пути с расчётом на то, что скрипт будет вызываться через запрос к сайту. При запуске такого скрипта через cron относительность пути ломается и нужный файл не подключается. Исправить это можно, если добавить в начало вызываемого скрипта следующий код:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'имя_сайта';
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = 'IP_адресс';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';
chdir('/var/www/application/www/и/далее/путь/к/папке/скрипта');
```

Answer (score 1):

Через wget получилось.

```html
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://site.ru/main/cron/index?token=TOKEN > /tmp/lcron.log 2>&1
```

Спасибо! С днем программиста всех!